# What happened to the original opening scene to "Whom Gods Destroy"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I remember seeing the uncut episode of "Whom Gods Destroy" (TOS, Episode 3x16) in the 1970's which included a scene with Kirk, Spock and Scotty discussing the security question involving chess move "queen to queen level 3", at the very beginning of this episode on the Enterprise!  Since then, I have never seen it again. Now, the episode starts with Kirk and Spock beaming down to the planet Elba II while Kirk is speaking his Stardate explanation of the episode.

Does anyone remember this scene, and what happened to it?  It is neither on any official DVD set, original, or remastered!

Comment: Yeah.  The scene existed.  Without it, the security question later seems to come from nowhere.  I'd have to dig out my DVDs and find it to see if it's there or not.

Comment: [The transcript at Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/71.htm) might be helpful for tracking this down. It does include a conversation between Kirk and Scotty. However, I've not really watched any _Star Trek_ to know if this is what you're referring to and it does happen a bit after the intro.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot:  The transcript is also missing the scene.  It took place on the Enterprise before Kirk beamed down.  The transcript starts on the planet.

Comment: @JRE Ah okay, I was wondering if it might have been a misremembering of the scene starting with Scotty saying _"Scott here, sir"_.

Comment: Interestingly the [Memory Alpha page for the episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Whom_Gods_Destroy_(episode)) doesn't seem to say anything about this.

Comment: The version of the episode available on Netflix right now also lacks that scene - although I, too, seem to remember it from long ago, I don't know whether my memory is playing tricks.  Maybe it's in the novelization?

Comment: No, it's not in the James Blish novelization "Star Trek 3".  It starts with Kirk and Spock already on the planet, and out of the blue mentions the password Scott and Kirk had previously worked out.

Comment: There is some discussion of a recovered scene from _Whom Gods Destroy_ here, although I don’t think it’s the one you remember: http://startrekhistory.com/article2.html I found it linked from [this interview](https://sciencefiction.com/2018/12/18/exclusive-interview-star-trek-lost-scenes-authors-david-tilotta-curt-mcaloney-part-2/) with the authors of a book called “Star Trek: Lost Scenes”, which might be worth a look.

Comment: no mention in the generally comprehensive "These Are the Voyages" series

Comment: Mandela effect aside - there is a certain logic to the audience being as in the dark as Garth was for the proper response.

Comment: @Robert  This is a good question, whether the scene was real or a figment of your imagination.